# GPS provider not return my current location android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, locationmanager

I am trying to get user current location but my onLocationChanged method never get called.I have added permissions in Manifest.xml also,But onLocationChange method never get called.
I have open GPS of my device and try it on two different mobile but not working.
Below is my code -

```
public class LocationAwareActivity extends Activity implements
         LocationListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Current onLocationChanged : "+location.getLatitude()+" , "+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStatusChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onProviderEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onProviderDisabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and below is code of manifest.xml -

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

TIA

Comment: I believe that the problem may be interference in receiving the satellite signal in the area where the device was located. Try going to some outside environment. I performed the experiment and it worked after moving to an open area (I was inside a building)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use the new Fused location provider for fetching the location.

The Fused Location Provider intelligently manages the underlying location technology and gives you the best location according to your needs.

Refer below links:
```

1. https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html
2. http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/
3. http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html

Comment: Sure, i want to know one more thing- i want to get user location after every 60 seconds.and also want to show notification while user enters a geofance . can you please share your idea.how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you obtain Google Map Key?
add it on your project. like this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your Google Map Key" />
```

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

Comment: I dont want to show it on a map,I just need it for some other purpose.

Comment: Are u sure u are in outdoor? GPS don't have result in indoor places.

Comment: No, I am in a building..But i think it should work.It may be not accurate but it should return my last known location at least once.

Comment: No. u should go out. then after once it has inaccurate result in buildings.

Comment: I agree with jion, it will not return your location unless it has some GPS satellites in sight. Try to go outside.

Answer (score 0):

You might not get location updates since you do not move.

Try changing this line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
```

To this:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```